# Calculated field to show the greater of two calculated values

Tags: calculated-column

I have some documents that need to be deleted based on the following criteria: one year after termination, or three years after hire date, whichever is greater. I have created two calculated columns showing the purge dates based on the hire/term, but need to show the greater of the two for my filter. Can someone provide some guidance on how to create  a calculated field to show the greater of the two values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a reference here is the [msdn article on calculated field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx)

The basic is that you convert the dates to integers, and then use the max function to get the largest value.

So something like: (Please note date/time string format depends on where you are so check it!)

```
=TEXT(MAX(INT([column1]),INT([column2])), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```